# Can pattern matching go across TCP packets?

Tags: regex, tcp, pattern-matching, snort, intrusion-detection

I am new to Intrusion Detection system. From what I know, it seems the pattern matching (e.g., PCRE in Snort) only search matches within a packet.

**Can pattern matching go across packets?**

In practice, do people care about cross-packets patterns?

Comment: How is that related to [tag:pattern-matching]? Did you mean  [tag:pattern-recognition]?

Comment: but you can't hold up packets because somewhere down the timeline you want to match packet 5 where packet 50 != packet 4 which contains `[0-9]+^&` therefore lets match a book across the next 200 packets. you can see the problem cant you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing stream reassembly (which should be enabled by default in the standard snort.conf) then yes. This is called the pseudo packet (or reassembled packet) which snort builds from multiple packets and reassembles. You can read about this functionality and configuration for it [here](https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-stream5). This is probably the most important part of snort (and most expensive), without stream reassembly many many exploits would be missed. Without reassembly snort would only be able to inspect the raw packets. For example:

TCP Packet contains 2000 bytes of data, the MTU on the network is 1500, so this packet must be chopped up into separate packets to be sent. Say 1400 bytes are sent in packet 1 and the other 600 bytes in packet 2. If there is an exploit within this packet and the content that snort is looking for is contained within bytes 1360-1500 then snort would miss the exploit and would not alert. With stream reassembly snort will reassemble the packet:

Say you have a snort rule looking for the content "THIS IS AN EXPLOIT".

Raw packet 1: ....data...THIS IS AN
Raw packet 2: EXPLOIT....data...

Without stream reassembly snort would miss this exploit. With stream reassembly snort will rebuild the pseudo packet and it will run the rule content against that so it will see:

Pseudo packet: ...data...THIS IS AN EXPLOIT...data...

And the rule will match.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your detailed explanation. As I know TCP packets arrive out of order (correct me), (1) does this mean Snort can only inspect the packets have been ordered so far?  (2) Also does this prevent any parallel processing among packets?

Comment: This is very complex in Snort. But to put it very simply, Snort will inspect the raw packets as they come in and also queue them up for reassembly until it has enough to flush to detection (basically until it receives an ACK from the other side). It then flushes to detection and inspects the reassembled packet. So out of order packets won't matter as long as it eventually sees all of them AND an ACK from the other side. If it sees an exploit in a raw packet it will blacklist the session, if it sees the pattern in the pseudo packet and it is in pre-ack mode it will drop the ACK and blacklist.